# How does pytest_plugin Global variable works?

Tags: python, pytest

I was trying to define bunch fixtures in one file say redis.py (abc\plgfix\redis.py) and use them in my test cases (abc\common\test_file.py) via pytest_plugin.  While doing that I notice test cases couldn't see fixtures I defined.

My Folder structure is as follows

```
abc
  |
  common
     |
      config.py    ( I have defined pytest_plugin=["plgfix.redis"]
      test_file.py
  plgfix
     |
      redis.py ( I have defined bunch of fixtures here)
      __init__.py
```

From above illustration

```
-> plgfix (folder) has my desired  file(redis.py) and __init__.py file to 
   make folder  as package.

-> In  abc\common\config.py. I have defined pytest_plugin global variable

     pytest_plugins = ["plgfix.redis"] #assuming all fixtures in 
                                 #redis.py file , available for test cases



->  Now I have created abc\common\test_file.py where I'm  using one of the 
    defined fixture in redis.py (abc\plgfix\redis.py) as follows.

     def test_fixtu(fix1):
          print ("Hi")
          pass


 I was getting error as  fix1 is not found
```

Note : I can able to import config file and see contents as '**package**', '**spec**', 'pytest_plugins'....... (confirming it is not path issue)

Comment: Rename `config.py` to `conftest.py` and move it to the project root.

Comment: I have renamed  file to conftest.py and move to root folder (here abc/). Still I see fixture not found error. In addition to this I tried moving test file to root folder,though error is same. I removed all .cache file as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#globalvar-pytest_plugins), the global var is supposed to be either a `str` or a `Sequence[str]`. You seem to have assigned a list to it.